# model and collection to one view in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, view, collections, model

Being new to Backbone.js, I want to ask one general and simple question. In my app I need to create a new view with giving a collection and a model in it.

```
var myView = new SomeView({
    model: myModel,
    collection: myCollection,
    el:$('#main_content')});
}});
```

Interestingly, I got my stuff worked. What do you think if it suits with the concept of backbone, or what?

Thank you..

Comment: there is nothing wrong giving a model and collection to a view. However I will be a bit skeptical about the overall architecture. Why would a view need a model and a collection ? in most cases, you would be better off splitting the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason you can't do that, but it's a bit confusing. Normally you can infer the type of the model or collection from the name of the view. For example, the `collection` of `EmployeeListView` will probably be a `EmployeeCollection`, and the `model` or `CompanyView` will most likely be a `Company`.

But when you have both a model and a collection, the meaning is not clear. In such case I would name the parameters more meaningfully. The `model` and `collection` properties are just conventions - Backbone views don't really need either.

Let's say you have a view that displays a `Company` and it's `Employee`s:

```
var CompanyEmployeesView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.company = options.company;
    this.employees = options.employees;
  }
});

var view = new CompanyEmployeesView({
  company: company,
  employees: employeesCollection
});
```